# Как правильно достать данные из LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, localstorage, jsx

У меня есть форма в которой  пишется название количество страниц, потом я отдельно записываю количество страниц в LocalStorage. Потом не должен их получать  и суммировать. Но я получаю из LocalStorage количества страниц через запятую. Как я могу их разделить и суммировать.

Код где я записываю в LocalStorage

```
    addBook=async(name,count)=>{
        let bookInfo = {};
        bookInfo["name"] = name;
        bookInfo["count"] = count;
        await this.setState({
            booksList: [...this.state.booksList,bookInfo],
            nameValue: "",
            countValue: 0,
            booksPages: [...this.state.booksPages,count]
        })
        localStorage.setItem("booksList",JSON.stringify(this.state.booksList));
        localStorage.setItem("booksPages",(this.state.booksPages));
    }
```

Код где я беру из LocalStorage

```
componentDidMount(){
        const booksList = localStorage.getItem('booksList');
        const booksPages = localStorage.getItem('booksPages');
        console.log("booksPages",booksPages)
        if(booksList){
            const savedList = JSON.parse(booksList);
            this.setState({
                booksList : savedList,
                booksPages: booksPages
            })
        }else{
            console.log("No list")
        }
    }
```

Например я ввожу
Test 100
Test 100

То получаю в booksPages 100,100
Как мне это исправить

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно так же, как Вы это делаете для `booksList`.

```
localStorage.setItem("booksPages",JSON.stringify(this.state.booksPages));
...
const booksPages = localStorage.getItem('booksPages')? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('booksPages')) : [];
const pageSum = booksPages.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i, 0);
```